# Humax ND 1000 C set top box

Tags: robotics, embedded, linux

I have an old settop box, model - humax nd 1000c. I no longer use it for my TV since the city I've moved to doesnt have the relevant service provider (afaik).

I want to try and hack into the box to just fiddle around with its OS (I believe it to be some flavor of embedded linux) and use it in my robotics projects if possible. I've done a large amount of surfing on the web but haven't really found anything I can use to get ahead. Plus, the fact that the box doesnt have a serial/parallel/usb out compounds my problem. It just has a i/p for a co-ax cable (I assume) and RCA o/p's. Is there any way I can interface with this guy?

Let me know if a picture or other details will help.

Comment: Can you post or link to high-res photos of the PCB?  Flatbed scanners work well for this if there are no tall components.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely a serial interface somewhere on the PCB itself, maybe even a header. Open the sucker up and look for suspicious 2-6-pin connections. You may be able to get a part number off of the main micro -- look up the datasheet for its JTAG, ISP, 1-Wire or other programming pins. There's always the possibility that this thing was programmed before being soldered in, but there should still be some kind of test rig setup to interface with it -- with a bit of luck and ingenuity, you may be able to hack even that into a programmer.